# Why position: absolute does not take my div out from the content flow?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project which displays a map and if you select the country displays information about the given country.

The map has to be the whole size of the page.

And the modal should be hidden until the user selected the country.

I want to display the modal on the left side of the map and display:block if the country selected.

I try position absolute for the modal but it still follows the normal
content flow and displays it below the map.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#mapid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 97%;
}

#modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-item row" id="selectDiv">
  <select class="col-12" id="select" name="country"></select>
</div>


<div class="box map" id="mapid"></div>

<div id="modal">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore sed fugit velit voluptatibus, quae, nulla saepe fugiat in quo, debitis ipsa ullam corporis deserunt. Fugit repudiandae accusantium illum tempora quia.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: Because you haven't told the element **where to be**. So it defaults to where it would be until you apply some top/bottom/right/left values

Comment: absolute witout coordonates will set the element where it should have been in the flow without disturbing the flow.

Comment: [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute) to the behaviour described by the other comments.